# A Python wrap-around list

Tags: python, object-oriented, inheritance, circular-list

I want to gain experience creating data structures that look and feel like Python builtin types. As a first exercise, I've written a `WraparoundList` class meant to be identical to the builtin `list`, except that accessing out-of-bounds elements "wraps around".

Goals:

- The only behavior that differs from that of a `list` is when explicitly indexed with `[]`.
- Should look and feel like the Python builtin, i.e., wouldn't look *too* out of place in the `collections` module.
- Should be compatible with both Python 2.7.x and 3.x (though I only have tested on 2.7.13).

The complete source code with doctests follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import maxint as MAXINT

class WraparoundList(list):
    """A list whose index wraps around when out of bounds.

    A `WraparoundList` is the same as an ordinary `list`, 
    except that out-of-bounds indexing causes the index 
    value to wrap around. The wrapping behavior is as if
    after reaching the last element, one returned to the 
    other end of the list and continued counting.

    >>> x = WraparoundList('abcd')
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    >>> x[3]
    'd'
    >>> x[4] # wraps to x[0]
    'a'
    >>> x[-6] = 'Q' # wraps to x[-2]
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'Q', 'd']
    >>> del x[7] # wraps to x[3]
    >>> x 
    ['a', 'b', 'Q']

    Indices used in out-of-range slices also wrap around.
    If the slice's `start` or `stop` is out-of-bounds, it 
    gets wrapped around.

    >>> x = WraparoundList('abcd')
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    >>> x[:10] # wraps to x[:2]
    ['a', 'b']
    >>> x[-7:3] # wraps to x[-3:3]
    ['b', 'c']

    The one way in which slicing a `WraparoundList` differs 
    from slicing an ordinary `list` is the case of using the
    list length as the upper limit.

    >>> x = WraparoundList('abcd')
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    >>> x[2:]
    ['c', 'd']
    >>> x[2:4] # wraps to x[2:0]
    []

    Initializing a `WraparoundList` with a nested iterable
    does not cause inner indices to wrap. To have a multi-
    dimensional `WraparoundList`, all the elements of the 
    outer `WraparoundList` must also be `WraparoundList`s.

    >>> x = WraparoundList([list('abc'), list('def')])
    >>> x
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
    >>> x[3]
    ['d', 'e', 'f']
    >>> x[3][5]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: list index out of range
    >>> y = WraparoundList([WraparoundList(i) for i in x])   
    >>> y[3][5]
    'f'
    """
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """x.__getitem__(i) <=> x[i]"""
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return list.__getitem__(self, self._wrap_slice(i))
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, self._wrap_index(i))

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        """x.__getslice__(i, j) <=> x[i:j]"""
        return self.__getitem__(slice(i, j, None))

    def __setitem__(self, i, y):
        """x.__setitem__(i, y) <=> x[i] = y"""
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            list.__setitem__(self, self._wrap_slice(i), y)
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self, self._wrap_index(i), y)

    def __setslice__(self, i, j):
        """x.__setslice__(i, j) <=> x[i:j] = y"""
        self.__setitem__(slice(i, j, None))

    def __delitem__(self, i):
        """x.__delitem__(i, y) <=> del x[i]"""
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            list.__delitem__(self, self._wrap_slice(i))
        else:
            list.__delitem__(self, self._wrap_index(i))

    def __delslice__(self, i, j):
        """x.__delslice__(i, j) <=> del x[i:j]"""
        self.__delitem__(slice(i, j, None))

    def _wrap_index(self, i):
        _len = len(self)
        if i >= _len:
            return i % _len
        elif i < -_len:
            return i % (-_len)
        else:
            return i

    def _wrap_slice(self, slc):
        if slc.start is None:
            start = None
        else:
            start = self._wrap_index(slc.start) 
        if slc.stop is None:
            stop = None
        elif slc.stop == MAXINT:
            # __*slice__ methods treat absent upper bounds as sys.maxint, which would
            # wrap around to a system-dependent (and probably unexpected) value. Setting 
            # to `None` in this case forces the slice to run to the end of the list.
            stop = None
        else:
            stop = self._wrap_index(slc.stop)
        step = slc.step
        return slice(start, stop, step)

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'd recommend calling it a circular list

Comment: @theonlygusti Considered that, but thought that it may be too suggestive of an infinite iterable *a la* `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: Interestingly, `itertools.cycle` does not appear to have real Python source code, apart from being plugged into the Python object API. The source is here in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L854-L1054

Comment: In case you didn't know, *negative* indices already wrap around in regular Python lists and other sequence types.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Not sure what you mean. `x=range(4); x[-10]` raises `IndexError`, at least in 2.7.13. Do you mean "wrap" in a different sense?

Comment: @Endulum Indeed it behaves a bit differently than I expected. But still, for a list with 4 items, indices -1, -2, -3, -4 will work, accessing the list counting from the last element.

Comment: This question was posted as an answer by [auspicious_day](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/155836/auspicious-day) (and will likely be removed) "_is your (re) implementation available anywhere? I'd find it helpful if so. Thanks for posting._"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. This is well documented, well commented code.
2. The docstring says:

   > The one way in which slicing a `WraparoundList` differs from slicing an ordinary `list` is the case of using the list length as the upper limit.

   but this isn't quite the whole story — an ordinary `list` can also be sliced using a value *greater than* the list length, and in that case `WraparoundList` also has a different behaviour:

   ```
   >>> x = [1, 2, 3]
   >>> x[:10]
   [1, 2, 3]
   >>> x = WraparoundList(x)
   >>> x[:10]
   [1]
   ```
3. The code is not portable to Python 3, because there's no `sys.maxint` (all integers in Python 3 are "long"). I suggest something like this:

   ```
   try:
       # In Python 2.7, when __*slice__ methods are called with no "stop"
       # value, sys.maxint is passed instead.
       from sys import maxint as NO_STOP
   except ImportError:
       # Python 3 does not have sys.maxint or use the __*slice__ methods.
       NO_STOP = object()
   ```

   I prefer a name like `NO_STOP` because it communicates the intention rather than the implementation.
4. `_wrap_index` raises `ZeroDivisionError` if the list is empty:

   ```
   >>> w = WraparoundList([])
   >>> w[0]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "cr153920.py", line 79, in __getitem__
       return list.__getitem__(self, self._wrap_index(i))
     File "cr153920.py", line 110, in _wrap_index
       return i % _len
   ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
   ```

   Raising an exception is the right thing to do in this case, but I would expect to get an `IndexError` instead.
5. The code calls `list.__getitem__` directly, rather than via the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) function. But this has the unsatisfactory consequence that if someone has another class `C` also inheriting from `list` and overriding the `__getitem__` method, and combines `WraparoundList` and `C` via inheritance, like this:

   ```
   class D(WraparoundList, C):
       pass
   ```

   Then `D()[0]` calls `WraparoundList.__getitem__`, which calls `list.__getitem__`, but `C.__getitem__` is never called, contrary to what one would expect.  If you want to support subclassing of `WraparoundList`, then you need to write:

   ```
   return super(WraparoundList, self).__getitem__(self._wrap_slice(i))
   ```

   and so on.
6. With a little refactoring, you could avoid some of the repetition. In particular, if you had a method like this:

   ```
   def _wrap_arg(self, i):
       if isinstance(i, slice):
           return self._wrap_slice(i)
       else:
           return self._wrap_index(i)
   ```

   Then you'd be able to write:

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, i):
       """x.__getitem__(i) <=> x[i]"""
       return super(WraparoundList, self).__getitem__(self._wrap_arg(i))
   ```

   and so on.
7. Once you've done the refactoring above, you'll see that `_wrap_slice` is only called from one place, so it could be inlined at its point of use.
8. There is no need to include an empty `main` function or an `if __name__ == '__main__':` section — if there's nothing to do, then there's no need to write code to do it.

Comment: Wonderful! One clarification: Do I understand correctly that the `__*slice__` methods are redundant if I'm handling slices in `__*item__`, even in 2.7.X?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__): "built-in types in CPython currently still implement `__getslice__()`. Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing."

Answer (score 0):

On top of Gareth Ree's excellent answer: because the `WraparoundList` and the usual `list` behave differently (for instance when sliced using a value greater than the list length), your class does not respect [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (see also [less formal explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)).

In a nutshell: because some code using a `list` would behave differently if it was to use a `WraparoundList`, then `WraparoundList` should not inherit from `list` even if the "WraparoundList is a list" relationship is respected.

A way to change this could be to stop inheriting from `list` but instead to use a `list` internally to store data ([Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).